# How do I retrieve lat & long coordinates from the client without them needing to POST once?

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms, django-views, geodjango

I'd like to do some server side processing with their lat/long as soon as they agree to share them--I'd like for the results of that processing to be in the same page the users are in, immediately after they "Allow" location access.

Currently, I am able to retrieve their coordinates, but a POST removed. So when they "Allow", I fill out a hidden lat/long form, and wait for them to POST a form before I do the server side processing with Geodjango.

What's an efficient way to send over the coordinates to the server as soon as they're available, OR retrieve an estimated location, pronto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this easily:

- make a view that gets `POST` parameter as JSON

Python sample:

```
class MyJsonForAjaxView(generic.View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return JsonResponse({'key': value}, safe=False)
```

- call that view in JavaScript (= AJAX call) with POST method:

JavaScript code:

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'post',
    type: 'json',
    cache: false,
    url: 'my_json_url',
    data: {'lat': your_lat, 'lgn': your_lgn}
}).done(function(data) {
    alert('call successfull!!!');
    /* data is filled with Django result, here {'key': value} */
    /* todo: remember the call has been made and it's registered on Django side */
}).fail(function(data) {
    alert('fatal error!');
}).always(function() {
    /* whatever the result, always do something here */
});
```

You can do this in the background as soon as you have what you need

Comment: If the ajax `method` is `'post'`, should the function in the CBV not also be a `def post`? And vice versa? I have tried it both ways, and they both seem to work, strangely.. But not when they conflict.